# Run a migration script where a column is created and then updated

Tags: sql-server

I have this script where I want to add a SurveyId and remove a ContractId from the SOR table.
However the script will not run because the SurveyId is created in the script and is considered to be an invalid column as it does not exist before it is created.
So how do I fix this?
See

```
-- Start of script
PRINT 'Start of script'

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    information_schema.COLUMNS
                WHERE   table_schema = 'dbo'
                        AND TABLE_NAME = 'Sor'
                        AND column_Name = 'ContractId' )
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The colmun ContractId does not exist in Sor table' 
        GOTO EndScript
    END

BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    GOTO ErrorScript
END

PRINT 'Begin Transaction'

-- Add the new SurveyId field to both Questions and SOR
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    information_schema.COLUMNS
                WHERE   table_schema = 'dbo'
                        AND TABLE_NAME = 'Sor'
                        AND column_Name = 'SurveyId' )
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The colmun SurveyId already exists in Sor table' 
        GOTO RemoveUnwantedData
    END

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sor]
ADD SurveyId int null
IF @@ERROR <> 0
 BEGIN
    PRINT 'Error: ' + CAST(@@ERROR AS VARCHAR(10)) + '. Failed to add SurveyId column to the Sor table.'
    GOTO ErrorScript
 END

 PRINT 'SurveyId column successfully added to the Sor table'

RemoveUnwantedData:
-- Remove ContractId = 0 - invalid rows

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Sor]
WHERE ContractId = 0
IF @@ERROR <> 0
 BEGIN
    PRINT 'Error: ' + CAST(@@ERROR AS VARCHAR(10)) + '. Failed to delete ContractId = 0 in the Sor table.'
    GOTO ErrorScript
 END

PRINT 'Removed rows in Sor where ContractId = 0, if there are any'
-- Create a query to populate the SurveyId

 UPDATE [dbo].[Sor] 
 SET SurveyId = vw.SurveyId -- **<----ERROR HERE!!!!!!!! --**
  FROM dbo.FirstSurveyIdForContractId vw WHERE vw.ContractId = dbo.Sor.ContractId
IF @@ERROR <> 0
 BEGIN
    PRINT 'Error: ' + CAST(@@ERROR AS VARCHAR(10)) + '. Failed to populate SurveyId in the Sor table.'
    GOTO ErrorScript
 END

 PRINT 'SurveyIds successfully populated in the Sor table'

 -- Check if SurveyId can be made not null
 DECLARE @NumberOfNullEntriesSors INT
 SELECT @NumberOfNullEntriesSors = COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Sor] WHERE SurveyId IS NULL
IF @NumberOfNullEntriesSors > 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'There are ' + CAST(@NumberOfNullEntriesSors as VARCHAR(10)) + ' SurveyIds for SORs not set, check the data before proceeding'
    GOTO EndScript
END

 PRINT 'All SurveyIds set and now SurveyId can be made not null.'
 -- Alter SurveyId to not null

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sor]
 ALTER COLUMN SurveyId int NOT NULL
 IF @@ERROR <> 0
 BEGIN
    PRINT 'Error: ' + CAST(@@ERROR AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Failed to set SurveyId for Sor table to not null'
    GOTO ErrorScript
 END

 PRINT 'SurveyId now not null'

 -- Create new foreign key relationships for SurveyId

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sor] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Sor_Survey] 
 FOREIGN KEY ([SurveyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Survey] ([ID])
 IF @@ERROR <> 0
 BEGIN
    PRINT 'Error: ' + CAST(@@ERROR AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Failed to set foreign key SurveyId for Sor table.'
    GOTO ErrorScript
 END


PRINT 'Foreign key relationships set for Sor tables on SurveyId'

 -- Remove the ContractId column
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sor]
DROP COLUMN ContractId
IF @@ERROR <> 0
 BEGIN
    PRINT 'Error: ' + CAST(@@ERROR AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Failed to drop ContractId column from Sor table.'
    GOTO ErrorScript
 END


PRINT 'ContractId column dropped from SOR tables'

 GOTO SuccessScript

 ErrorScript:
 PRINT 'ErrorScript Started'
 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
 PRINT 'ErrorScript Completed'
 GOTO Endscript

 SuccessScript:
 Print 'SuccessScript Started'
 COMMIT TRANSACTION
 PRINT 'SuccessScript Completed'
 EndScript:
 Print 'End of Script'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) after the `ALTER TABLE` statement and before the `UPDATE` statement.

> Signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL
>   Server utilities.

Also, because a transaction cannot span more than 1 batch, you need to break your transaction up into 2 transactions.  An alternative to using `GOTO` for error handling in this situation is to use `TRY`/`CATCH` for each transaction as follows:

```
-- first batch
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY
    ...
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sor]
    ADD SurveyId int null
    ...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO

-- second batch
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY
    ...
    UPDATE [dbo].[Sor] 
    SET SurveyId = vw.SurveyId -- **<----ERROR HERE!!!!!!!! --**
    FROM dbo.FirstSurveyIdForContractId vw WHERE vw.ContractId = dbo.Sor.ContractId
    ...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

Comment: If I did that GOTO will not work. Maybe I should use RaiseError instead of GOTO?

Comment: OK gotcha... I think you might have to break your script into 2 transactions.  You can use `TRY`/`CATCH` to handle the rollback so you won't have a single `ErrorScript` label to jump to.

Comment: 2 transactions are the correct answer. Also used Try Catch in preference to GOTO